# Options for Silverlight desktop app, Windows and Mac, with local database

Tags: silverlight, desktop-application, sterling-db

I am evaluating options for a desktop app which needs to support both Windows and Mac, and given the resources we have available, it seems that Silverlight might be the best option. We would be looking at building a Silverlight 4 Out Of Browser app and using something similar to [what is described here](http://sharppdf-sl.sourceforge.net/offlineoob.html) to make a Mac installer.

However one major sticking point I can see is that the app will need local data storage, and by far the most useful way of storing said data would be in a local relational database (requirements are probably in the ballpark of hundreds of thousands of records, in ten or tables, in a very relational structure).

I've done some searching and found some options mentioned in the past, but in quite old questions so I'm not sure the information is current.

- [siaqodb](http://siaqodb.com/) - object database engine with LINQ querying
- [Sterling](http://www.sterlingdatabase.com/) - NoSQL database that can use memory, isolated storage, even the local file system to persist data

Before I get my hands dirty doing some experiments, can anyone offer any guidance on (a) whether **siaqodb** and/or **Sterling** will work in a Mac Out Of Browser environment storing data on the local filesystem, and (b) how "ready for prime time" **siaqodb** and **Sterling** are for commercial software development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm involved in Siaqodb project so full disclosure). We believe that Siaqodb is one of the most used client side database engine for Silverlight. It does fully support OOB on Windows and on Mac by storing data in "My..." folders for SL4 and starting with SL5 you can store anywhere on client machine. See [here](http://siaqodb.com/?page_id=280) what companies use Siaqodb. We are working now on the version 3.X which will bring extra features and soon extra supported platform.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Cristoph. I did spend a couple of hours yesterday doing some proof-of-concept experiments with Siaqodb and it seems to be going well so far.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Siaqodb, but I've worked with Sterling and it uses Isolated Storage, so it will work on a Mac. You can also use its FileSystemDriver which will then store it's data to a location you specify. That should also work, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think its ready for prime time, nothing to do with the technology itself, its just that Microsoft has killed it. The platform has no future.

https://everythingexpress.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/news-microsoft-kills-silverlight/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not really interested in opinions on the future or lack of it of Silverlight, just knowledgeable answers regarding siaqodb, Sterling, or other local database storage options.

Comment: Your question also says, '(b) how "ready for prime time" they both are for commercial software development?' I stand by my answer because the platform no future. It won't be supported by Microsoft going forward and its not open source so there will be nobody maintaining it.

Comment: "they both" = siaqodb and Sterling. Sorry, I have edited the question to remove any potential misunderstandings.

Comment: I see now. Still though, I don't quite understand why you would make this decision from an engineering perspective. Is there some underlying business reason?

Comment: Yes - skillset availability encourages us towards Silverlight if it is capable of doing the job. And the timeframe of the project is such that Microsoft's future plans with regards to progressing or not progressing the Silverlight platform are not relevant to us.